# i cant load camera preview in my app but all other things working fine

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-camera

commenting the line "camerasource.start();" inside the try catch made preview appear,but cant do that because the face detector doesn't work.please help...
my mainactivity.java is

```
package com.example.android.drownsinessdetector;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.Detector;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.MultiProcessor;  
import com.google.android.gms.vision.Tracker;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.face.Face;
import com.google.android.gms.vision.face.FaceDetector;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
private static final String TAG = "Video";
int camIdx;

CameraSource cameraSource;
TextView textView;

private Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview mPreview;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mCamera=getCameraInstance();
    // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    FrameLayout preview = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    preview.addView(mPreview);

    Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);


   createCameraSource();
}

private Camera getCameraInstance() {
    int inf = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT;
        Camera c = null;
        try {
            c = Camera.open(inf);
        } catch (Exception e){

        }
        return c;

}

public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;
        this.mCamera=camera;

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        Log.d(TAG,"camera preview class");
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

//This class will use google vision api to detect eyes
private class EyesTracker extends Tracker<Face> {

    private final float THRESHOLD = 0.75f;

    private EyesTracker(){}

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Detector.Detections<Face> detections, Face face) {
        if (face.getIsLeftEyeOpenProbability() > THRESHOLD || face.getIsRightEyeOpenProbability() > THRESHOLD) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onUpdate: Eyes Detected");
            showStatus("Eyes Detected and open");

        }
        else {

            showStatus("Eyes Detected and closed");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMissing(Detector.Detections<Face> detections) {
        super.onMissing(detections);
        showStatus("Face Not Detected yet!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDone() {
        super.onDone();
    }
}

private class FaceTrackerFactory implements MultiProcessor.Factory<Face> {

    private FaceTrackerFactory() {

    }

    @Override
    public Tracker<Face> create(Face face) {
        return new EyesTracker();
    }
}

public void createCameraSource() {
    FaceDetector detector = new FaceDetector.Builder(this)
            .setTrackingEnabled(true)
            .setClassificationType(FaceDetector.ALL_CLASSIFICATIONS)
            .setMode(FaceDetector.FAST_MODE)
            .build();
    detector.setProcessor(new MultiProcessor.Builder(new FaceTrackerFactory()).build());

    cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(this, detector)
            .setRequestedPreviewSize(1024, 768)
            .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT)
            .setRequestedFps(30.0f)
            .build();

    try {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        cameraSource.start();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}



public void showStatus(final String message) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            textView.setText(message);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

}
```

}

my layout xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.75"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="63dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:text="face_not_found"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

my manifest file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.drownsinessdetector">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />[enter image description here][1]

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

i can see only black screen in the place of camera preview.but the eye and face detector is working properly.it shows the status message as eyes are opened or not.i want to show camera preview also.

Comment: Do you have camera permissions on your manifest and requested those permissions from the user?

Comment: Did you get the camera permission from the user side ?

Comment: Yes i had given permission from user side

Comment: Camera is working and it detects the face and eyes ..it can be understandable by seeing my text view which updates according to the situation.but in the view that i have created for camera preview onlyblack screen is seen.

Comment: Change `FrameLayout` to `SurfaceView`